Equivalence of Hawking Temperature Between Black Hole and its KK Reduction
Consider the following $2+1$ dimensional metric describing a stationary black hole:
$$ds^2 = g_{tt}dt^2+g_{rr}dr^2+g_{\theta t}d\theta dt+g_{\theta\theta}d\theta^2$$
Where $t$ is temporal coordinate, $r$ is radial coordinate and $\theta\sim\theta+2\pi$ is compact coordinate represents some circle $S^1_{\theta}$.
This system is obtained via a KK reduction from 3+1 dimensional metric with an extra circle $S^1_{\phi}$ overall the compact part of this metric is a-2 torus $S_{\theta}^1\times S_{\phi}^1$ and having the general metric:
$$ds^2 = G_{tt}dt^2+G_{rr}dr^2+G_{\theta t}d\theta dt+G_{\theta\theta}d\theta^2+G_{\theta \phi}d\theta d\phi+G_{\phi t}d\phi dt+G_{\phi \phi}d\phi^2$$
Where according to KK, have the following realation with the components $g$ of the reduced system:
$$G_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}+e^{2\sigma}A_{\mu}A_{\nu},\quad G_{\mu\phi}=e^{2\sigma}A_{\mu},\quad G_{\phi \phi }=e^{2\sigma};\quad\mu,\nu\in\{t,\theta\}$$
Where $e^{2\sigma}$ and $A_{\mu},\mu\in\{t,\theta\}$ are radion and gauge field included in the 2+1 dimensional reduced system respectively.
Now I am interested in calculating the Hawking temperature of this black hole with some horizon $r=r_s$ via surface gravity $\kappa$ which connected to the Hawking temperature via:
$$T_H=\frac{\kappa}{2\pi}$$
According to Wald GR book (section 12.5 page 332) the surface gravity is given by:
$$\kappa =\lim_{r\to r_s}(aV)$$
Where:
$$V=\sqrt{-\chi^a\chi_{a}}$$
$$a = \sqrt{\alpha_c\alpha^c},\quad \alpha_c=\frac{\partial_cV^2}{2V^2}$$ corresponds to some bifurcate Killing horizon which have a compatible Killing vector $\chi^a$.
In the reduced 2+1 this killing vector is given by:
$$\chi^a=\partial_t-\Omega_\theta \partial_\theta,\quad \Omega_{\theta}=\frac{g_{t\theta}}{g_{\theta\theta}}\Big{|}_{r=r_s}$$ as consequence $V$ that determine the Hawking temperature is given by:
$$V = \sqrt{-g_{tt}+2\Omega_{\theta}g_{\theta t}-\Omega_{\theta}^2g_{\theta\theta}} $$
The KK reduced system should restore completely the same physical quantities of the original theory including mass, entropy and temperature, and thus $V$ should be the same for the 3+1 dimensional system. I have tried to choose the following Killing vector for this system:
$$\chi ^a =\partial_t -\tilde{\Omega}_\theta\partial_\theta-\tilde{\Omega}_\phi\partial_{\phi },\quad \tilde{\Omega}_{\theta}=\frac{G_{t\theta}}{G_{\theta\theta}}\Big{|}_{r=r_s},\tilde{\Omega}_{\phi}=\frac{G_{t\phi}}{G_{\phi\phi}}\Big{|}_{r=r_s} $$
as consequence $V$ that determine the Hawking temperature is given by:
$$V = \sqrt{-G_{tt}+2\tilde{\Omega}_{\theta}G_{\theta t}-\tilde{\Omega}_{\theta}^2G_{\theta\theta}+2\tilde{\Omega}_{\phi}G_{\phi t}-\tilde{\Omega}_{\phi}^2G_{\phi\phi}-2\tilde{\Omega}_{\theta}\tilde{\Omega}_{\phi}G_{\theta\phi }} $$
However, when comparing according to the relation between metric $G$ and $g$ above there is a mismatch in the value of $V$ and as consequnce a mismatch in the temperature, what should be the right Killing vector for the 3+1 dimensional system so the two system will match?
